# Need sum of data rows and columns using R

Tags: r

I need to get the sum of my data from the rows and columns. I uploaded my data in csv and then removed NA to replace them with zeros. I just can’t get my data to read as integers and the sum it up.

```
data<-read.csv("DataSet.2.csv",header=FALSE)
 mode(data)
 [1] "list"
 data[is.na(data)]=0
```

data

```
            V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10    V11
1              Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4 Var_5 Var_6 Var_7 Var_8 Var_9 Var_10
2         Crow     8     8     0     3     2     4     4    44     0     23
3        Mouse     2     0     5     4     2     6    36   636     2      2
4         Boar    15   113    48    36    15    66    14     0     2     23
5        Plain     8    17   164    14    91     0     6    10     6     32
6  Silver.Carp     3     1     0     6     7     0    35    35     0    432
7          Dog     1     0    27     0     0    11     0     0     7     43
8        Bingo     2     3     1    15     1    21     0     0     1      0
9    Chrysalis     1     0     2     0    47     0     0     0     7      3
10       Apple     2     0     3     0     0     0     0     0     5      4
11        Cork     3     0     1     0   461     8  2305    15     0      2
12         Ant    11     0     2     0     0     0     0    91     4      0
13    Cat.Claw     2    22     1   110     2     7    10     7     0      0
14    Aardvark     3     1     0     5    25    30   125     0     5      4
15    Carriage     0     3     3    15     0   533     0     1     7      3
16    Airplane     3     2     1    10     0    28     0    47     7      1
17     Clipper     2     1     2     5     0   507     0     0    23      2
18   Armadillo     3     2     4    11    24     0     2    10  3322      0
19        Cork     3     3     1     9   461    88  2305    15   233      3
20        Colt     3     4     1    10  4902     0     0     1  4322    111
21         Cat     3    22     2   220     3    11    10     7  2333     22
      V12
1  Var_11
2      15
3       4
4      13
5       3
6     312
7       1
8      22
9      12
10      0
11      0
12     23
13     32
14     44
15     43
16      2
17     33
18      2
19      3
20     55
21      3
```

#When I use as.numeric I am getting an error

> data2<-as.numeric(data)
> Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you add a piece of your data to your answer. The way you show it does not reveal anything about the internal data structure and the data types. You can do that using `dput(head(data))` and add it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your .csv file contains a header ('Var_1', 'Var_2', etc.) but you are specifying header=FALSE when you load the data, so those strings are being interpreted as data values. Additionally, it looks like your first column represents row names for your dataset. You can specify this via the `row.names` argument.

Instead, load the data using:

`data <- read.csv("DataSet.2.csv", header=TRUE, row.names = 1)`

Once the data is loaded you can get the column and row sums via the functions `colSums()` and `rowSums()`, respectively. Additionally, if you are replacing the NA values with 0s just for the computation of the sums, you can skip that skip by setting the parameter, `na.rm = TRUE` within `colSum()` and `rowSums()`. This will remove the NA values from the collection of the sums. For example:

```
data <- read.csv("DataSet.2.csv", header=TRUE, row.names = 1)
row_sum <- rowSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)
col_sum <- colSums(data, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank You this helped. I am new to coding and still learning things.